# Android Wear - Install signed apk through mobile successfully but sync data failed

Tags: wear-os

I package the wearable app into the handheld app manually by using eclipse  wearable app had installed successfully.But when syncing data from handheld to wear, it is nothing to happen.I am sure the sign key was same.

Strangely, Using the same code I debugging install wearable app over bluetooth, data sync ok. I am sure that sending message was success on mobile, i guess onMessageReceived() didn't work on wear.I don't know.

Somebody help me, thanks!

Comment: I don't know how you are packaging the wearable app inside the phone app "manually using eclipse" but first, please explain how you know the packaging and also the installation of wear app has been successful; secondly it is strongly recommended to migrate to Android Studio so that new tooling can be used with the IDE. You mentioned that if you install the wearable app using "adb", all works; if that is correct, then your packaging is an issue; you may be able to see the error if you look at the logs for your devices when you install the phone app.

Comment: According to this page (http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html), i packaged the wearable app inside the phone.

Comment: i know the packaging and also the installation of wear app has been successful because i can start the phone app and wear app,but i can't sync data from phone to watch

Comment: I fixed it. When pachaging i choose the wrong alies...Thank for the help of Ali